# Understanding the whole process of a "web transaction"

Tags: jsp, http, servlets, servlet-container

I was doing some researches in order to understand the hole image of a "web transaction": the request from client to a server then the response from the server to the client.

The technologies concerned by my reads are : servlets container, servlet, JSP.

I summarize in the following steps what I've understood:

1. The client send an HTTPrequest
2. The HTTP server receive it and transmit it to the servlet container
3. The servlet container creates two objects for this HTTP request: HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse
4. A servlet Instanciates a Bean and Initialise its properties:

`SomeBean someBean = new SomeBean()`
`someBean.setProp("value")`

5. The servlet stocks the bean in the request as an attribute:
   `request.setAttribute("bean", someBean)`
6. The servlet transmits the request to the JSP file:

   `this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/JSPFile.jsp").forward( request, response );`
7. The JSPFile uses the information sent by the servlet:

   `package.SomeBean someBean = (package.SomeBean)`
     `request.getAttribute("bean");`
     `out.println( someBean.getProp());`
8. The JSPFile gets transformed to a servlet by the servlet container and sent to the client

The question: Correct me if I'm wrong, I want to understand the whole process.

Comment: *The JSPFile gets transformed to a servlet by the servlet container and sent to the client*: no. The compilation of a JSP to a servlet happens only once: at build time, or at deploy time, or when the JSP is first executed. And the servlet is not sent to the client. It's executed, and the execution consists in writing to the HttpServletResponse writer, i.e. to generate and send the body of the HTTP response.

Comment: @JBNizet considering your correction, I think the step number 6 needs correction too, it would be more correct to say: 6. The servlet transmits the request to the compiled JSPFile (whiche is a servlet)